# Doctrine entity manager using wrong connection

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

According to the [Symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html), multiple entity managers can be configured by listing them in `config/packages/doctrine.yaml` then selecting a specific entity manager in a controller like this: `$this->getDoctrine()->getManager('customer');`.

I set up my `config/packages/doctrine.yaml`:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                # configure these for your database server
                url: '%env(DATABASE_URL)%'
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '8.0'
                charset: utf8mb4
            meter:
                # configure these for your database server
                url: '%env(DATABASE_METER_URL)%'
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '8.0'
                charset: utf8mb4

    orm:
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                mappings:
                    App:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity'
                        alias: App
            meter:
                connection: meter
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                mappings:
                    App:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity'
                        alias: App
```

and then tried to make a query with

```php
$meterEntityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('meter');
$meter = $meterEntityManager->getRepository(Entity\Meter::class)->find($meterId);
```

However, the result of `$meterEntityManager->getRepository(Entity\Meter::class)->find($meterId)` is a row from the database connection named `default`, not the one named `meter` -- it is as if the code had been

```php
$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('default');
$meter = $entityManager->getRepository(Entity\Meter::class)->find($meterId);
```

When I check the connection with `$meterEntityManager->getConnection()->getParams()` it correctly lists the params for the `meter` connection rather than the `default` connection, so I can get a row from the `meter` database connection by executing queries directly on the connection object:

```php
$meterEntityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('meter');
$stmt = $meterEntityManager->getConnection()->prepare('SELECT * FROM meter WHERE id = :id');
$stmt->execute(['id' => $meterId]);
$meter = $stmt->fetch();
```

But ultimately I want to fetch rows through the methods offered by `getRepository(Entity\Meter::class)` so returned data is automatically hydrated into doctrine entities. There seems to be an inconsistency between the connection used by `$meterEntityManager->getRepository(Entity\Meter::class)` and `$meterEntityManager->getConnection()`. Why is this? Does it have something to do with the entity managers using different connections but sharing the same mappings to entities?

Comment: I'm guessing you have custom entity repositories and that they extend from ServiceEntityRepository?  If so, extend them from EntityRepository.  The ServiceEntityRepository does not properly handle the case where you have the same entities defined in multiple entity managers.

Comment: Yes, when I change `class MeterRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository` to `class MeterRepository extends EntityRepository`, however, it throws an exception when I try to call `getRepository(Entity\Meter::class)` saying `Argument 1 passed to App\Repository\MeterRepository::__construct() must implement interface Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface, instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager given, called in /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Repository/ContainerRepositoryFactory.php on line 84` see https://jsfiddle.net/4d97p3ot/ for full stack trace

Comment: Get rid of the constructor in your MeterRepository class completely.

Comment: That worked! Would you like to leave your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The basic issue here is that ServiceEntityRepository class iterates through a list of entity managers and uses the first one that supports a given entity.  Which is fine except when you happen to have entities supported by multiple entity managers.  The solution is to go "old school" and extend from the EntityRepository class instead of what is basically a container aware ServiceEntityRepository.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
class MeterRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    // Note: Do not override the constructor here
```

You also have to add the App\Repository directory to the list of excluded directories in services.yaml.

The reason for the ServiceEntityRepository was to allow the Symfony container to autowire repositories and inject them directly into other services.  It also allows the developer to inject additional dependencies into the repository if they so chose.

Comment: This is still a working solution for Symfony 5.

Comment: Works also for Symfony 6